# Google play services, please help

Tags: google-play-services, google-apps

So my Google play services won't update saying I need to sign in but when I try, it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Try below given possible solutions. I hope one of the below given tips fix Google Play services issues.

**1st Way: Clear the cache Google Play Services**

settings > Apps > Google Play services > Storage > Clear cache

If not work then clear all data of Google Play services storage using below settings.

**Settings > Apps > Google play services > Storage > Manage space > Clear all data**

**2nd Way: Uninstall Google play services updates**

Settings > Apps > Google Play services > More > Uninstall update > OK

**3rd Way: Remove your Google account**

**4th Way: Reset app preferences**

settings > Apps > More > Reset app preferences > Reset apps

If none of the above trick worked, check Google Play service version, **make sure latest version updated**.